# Синхронизация данных между сервисами

Tags: клиент-сервер, synchronized, микросервисы

Пишу на rust сервис на actix-web, который маштабируется до 4 запущенных экземпляров. Сервис находится за балансиром. Есть проблема в синхронизации данных на этих серверах. Данные получаются с БД каждым экземпляром каждые 10 минут и кешируются в памяти, постоянно делать запросы в БД по запросу клиента не представляется возможным, так как данные выбираются долго и общий их размер 30+ МБ.

**Пример:**

1. Клиент отправляет запрос и получает данные с первого сервера
2. Клиент снова отправляет запрос с данными полученными от первого сервера, но запрос падает на второй сервер, где данные еще не актуализированы, и следовательно он не в курсе, что за данные ему прислал клиент. По итогу запрос либо падает, либо происходит UB.

Вопрос, можно ли как-то наладить синхронизацию данных, чтобы на обоих серверах всегда были одни и те же данные в один момент времени?

Comment: Вы рассматривали варианты общего кэша в относительно быстрых NoSQL хранилищах? Например, в redis в бинарном виде данные сложить и обратно распарсивать.

Судя по вашей ситуации, кэш должен находиться вне инстансов приложения.

Comment: @SergeyK. на данный момент кэш находится внутри инстансов. Просто нагрузка на каждый инстанс +- 1000 RPS от клиентов. Так что для каждого запроса доставать 30+ МБ из Redis я думаю такое себе, так что я ее перестал рассматривать.
Была идея использовать дополнительный кэш внутри инстансов, который был бы не активен до того момента, пока все инстансы не обновят кэш у себя, а потом как-то понять, что все инстансы готовы использовать новые загруженные данные и переключиться на них.

Comment: Чтобы узнать все ли готовы можно в любой табличке бд или том же редисе или ещё где помечать версию данных кэша, которая на данный момент в инстансе лежит. Если у какого-то экземпляра есть новее, значит, всем нужно актуализировать.

Comment: @SergeyK. Появилась у меня одна идея. В вопросе я не уточнил, что данные хоть и огромные, но они поделены на маленькие структуры +- 1КБ, каждая структура имеет свой ID + версия. 
Идея: Каждый инстанс обновляет маленькие структуры по ключу в Redis, когда обновляет свой кэш из БД. Если остальные инстансы не имеют каких-то данных в момент запроса от клиента, то они пойдут в Redis и дополнят свой кэш нужными записями. 
+ Прежде чем инстанс переключится на новые загруженные данные из БД, он дополнит записи в Redis. Скорость актуализации данных из БД не важна, важны идентичные данные на инстансах